# Scala equivalent for 'matches' regex method?

Tags: regex, scala

Struggling with my first (ever) Scala regex here. I need to see if a given String matches the regex: "`animal<[a-zA-Z0-9]+,[a-zA-Z0-9]+>`".

So, some examples:

```
animal<0,sega>          =>    valid
animal<fizz,buzz>       =>    valid
animAl<fizz,buzz>       =>    illegal; animAl contains upper-case (and this is case-sensitive)
animal<fizz,3d>         =>    valid
animal<,3d>             =>    illegal; there needs to be something [a-zA-Z0-9]+ between '<' and ','
animal<fizz,>           =>    illegal; there needs to be something [a-zA-Z0-9]+ between ',' and '>'
animal<fizz,%>          =>    illegal; '%' doesn't match [a-zA-Z0-9]+
etc.
```

My best attempt so far:

```
val animalRegex = "animal<[a-zA-Z0-9]+,[a-zA-Z0-9]+>".r
animalRegex.findFirstIn("animal<fizz,buzz")
```

Unfortunately that's where I'm hitting a brick wall. `findFirstIn` and all the other obvious methods available of `animalRegex` all return `Option[String]` types. I was hoping to find something that returns a boolean, so something like:

```
val animalRegex = "animal<[a-zA-Z0-9]+,[a-zA-Z0-9]+>".r
if(animalRegex.matches("animal<fizz,buzz>")) {
    val leftOperand : String = getLeftOperandSomehow(...)
    val rightOperand : String = getRightOperandSomehow(...)
}
```

So I need the equivalent of Java's `matches` method, and then need a way to access the "left operand" (that is, the value of the first `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` group, which in the current case is "`fizz`"), and then ditto for the right/second operand ("`buzz`"). Any ideas where I'm going awry?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To be able to extract the matched parts from your string, you'll need to add capture groups to your regex expression, like so (note the parentheses):

```
val animalRegex = "animal<([a-zA-Z0-9]+),([a-zA-Z0-9]+)>".r
```

Then, you can use Scala's pattern matching to check for a match and extract the operands from the string:

```
val str = "animal<fizz,3d>"
val result = str match {
    case animalRegex(op1,op2) => s"$op1, $op2"
    case _                    => "Did not match"
}
```

In this example, `result` will contain `"fizz, 3d"`

Comment: What a beautiful answer. I don't know why they didn't provide `matches`, but the scaladoc says `A regular expression is used to determine whether a string matches a pattern and, if it does, to extract or transform the parts that match.` The idiom is `case animalRegex(_*) =>` if you only want to check if it matches, ignoring groups.